# Income tax filing for F-1 OPT student non-resident in California

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, california

I am an international student currently working full time on F-1 OPT status. In 2014, I worked as an intern for 3 months in California. I am confused if I should be filing 540NR short form or long form. Also should I be filing Schedule CA (540) NR? I did not have any other income other than California income. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you live in California for all of 2014?

Comment: No I did not. Only lived in California for 3 months during the summer.